# npm workspace - read dependency d.ts file as string

Tags: typescript, npm, vite, monaco-editor

I have a monorepo which uses the [npm workspace](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v10/using-npm/workspaces) feature. The packages can be built with using [vite](https://vitejs.dev/) and `d.ts` files are generated using [vite-plugin-dts](https://github.com/qmhc/vite-plugin-dts).

So lets say the project consists of two packages `Lib` and `App` in which `Lib` is a library and `App` is the frontend app which depends on `Lib`. Now I want to display a [monaco](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/) powered code editor in `App` which has has access to all types of `Lib`. This means that I have to somehow read the `*.d.ts` file of `Lib` as a string to set it as "extra lib" for monaco.

I guess the more general question is: How does one read build results from one package in another package? When building `App` using `npm run -w packages/app build`, vite is only executed for `App` i.e. some additional code-generation scripts of `Lib` are not run. Does npm itself has some kind of mechanism for this?